# How to check CUSTOM_RINGTONE have assigned to a Contact or not in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have designed a app, where i need to know. whether a Custom ringtone have been assigned to a particular contact or not. I just want to check CUSTOM_RINGTONE property column contains null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you looking at the ringtone data in Content Provider. As per the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#CUSTOM_RINGTONE